# CountTo Module animation doesn't work after currency pipe is added

Tags: html, angular, typescript, pipe, angular8

I need to have a final view like this:

[image]

The values will have a counter animation from 0 to the final value specified. And I introduced the currency pipeline in the value section for thousand's separator. But the counter animation stopped after that. It shows NaN as in the screenshot below and then the value specified comes up. I want to have the counter animation work along with the currency pipeline.

[image]

[image]

**dashboard.component.html**

```html
<div class="media-body col-8">
  <span class="m-0">Ad Offers / Value</span>
  <h3 class="mb-0">
    <span class="counter" [CountTo]="adOffersCount" [from]="0" [duration]="2">{{ adOffersCount }}
                                </span> /

    <span class="counter" [CountTo]="adOffersValue | currency:'INR':'symbol':'3.0'" [from]="0" [duration]="2">{{ adOffersValue }}
                                </span>

    <small> This Month</small>
  </h3>
</div>
```

**dashboard.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.scss']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

  adOffersCount= 10;  
  adOffersValue =6650;
  ngOnInit(){

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you have a look at the first line of what the currency pipe does => https://angular.io/api/common/CurrencyPipe it will tell you that it transforms a number to a currency string, formatted according to locale rules that determine group sizing and separator. And now you are assigning a specific string to your Count instead of a number. And why would you want to put a currency pipe there. It needs to be inside the extrapolation brackets.

```
    <span class="counter" [CountTo]="adOffersValue" [from]="0" [duration]="2">{{ adOffersValue | currency:'INR':'symbol':'3.0'}}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t3hbmh?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: I put the currency pipe there because the animation works due to count value only. Even if you remove the interpolated value, still it will work. As per your answer it will look like this. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GMbmQxp9uxPBvsnqYgLiONm5w-O2XN9e/view?usp=sharing

Comment: And I am not assigning a string to the counter. It's of 'number' datatype as you can see in the typescript code I attached above.

Comment: You are assigning a number, but the currency pipe is transforming this number to a string. Therefore the end value assigned to your 'CountTo' property is a string....

Comment: Ok! But now what? The number doesn't have any thousands separator or any other separator for the currency as per your code.

Comment: You are doing something else wrong which is not in this code snippet. Check the demo.